# Updating InfoWindow from Parse Query Google Maps Android

Tags: android, google-maps, parse-platform

I am trying to create a custom infowindow in my app by using the information I get from a Parse query. The problem I am running into is that I can only update the UI from the main thread and not a background process that Parse queries use.

```
map.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
                View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.info_window, null);
                TextView titleInfoWindow = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.titleInfoWindow);
                final TextView dateInfoWindow = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.dateInfoWindow);
                TextView timeInfoWindow = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.timeInfoWindow);
                TextView latitudeInfoWindow = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.latitudeInfoWindow);
                TextView sexInfoWindow = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.sexInfoWindow);
                TextView speciesInfoWindow = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.speciesInfoWindow);

                titleInfoWindow.setText(marker.getTitle());
                latitudeInfoWindow.setText(String.valueOf(marker.getPosition().latitude));


                ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("deletingTest");
                query.whereEqualTo("shark", marker.getTitle());
                query.whereEqualTo("latitude", String.valueOf(marker.getPosition().latitude));
                query.whereEqualTo("longitude", String.valueOf(marker.getPosition().longitude));
                query.setLimit(100);
                query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
                    public void done(List<ParseObject> scoreList, ParseException e) {
                        if (scoreList.size() == 0) {
                            Log.d("MainActivity", "0");
                        } else {
                            Log.d("MainActivity", String.valueOf(scoreList.size()));
                            dateInfoWindow.setText("22");
                        }
                    }
                });


            return v;
        }
    });
```

So the titleInfoWindow and the latitudeInfoWindow are being updated while dateInfoWindow is not as it is not on the main thread. What would be the best way to be able to update the infoWindow from the data I would get out of the Parse query?

Here is the XML file am using for the infoWindow layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:id="@+id/titleInfoWindow" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:id="@+id/dateInfoWindow"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:id="@+id/timeInfoWindow"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:id="@+id/latitudeInfoWindow"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:id="@+id/longitudeInfoWindow"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:id="@+id/sexInfoWindow"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:id="@+id/speciesInfoWindow"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please try to update your `infoWindow` information in `done` method

Comment: @bjiang I do attempt to with dateInfoWindow.setText("22") in the else clause; however, this does nothing to the infoWindow because, at least what I believe, this is not on the main thread and thus does not update the ui.

Comment: you can check whether you're trying to set text in main or background thread using log output - just pass the line `Thread.currentThread().getName()` to log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though the Parse query runs in a background thread, callback for this query executes in the main Ui-thread. So it shouldn't be the reason.

The reason why you can't correctly set your data is that you're inflating your custom layout in wrong method. [According to Google](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter.html)

> To replace the default info window, override getInfoWindow(Marker) with your custom rendering and return null for getInfoContents(Marker).

As you're trying not to replace content of default InfoWindow, but to inflate your own custom layout you have to move inflating to another method.

Comment: If I place it into the `getInfoMethod` and return the view it simply doesn't display anything; however, what I have in `getInfoContents` does update the `infoWindow` correctly except for the one line inside the `done` method of the parse query

Comment: According to Google, the `infoWindow` is a static image that can not be changed once it has been set. So I believe my `View v` is being returned before the parse query finishes and the done method runs because if I make changed to the textviews outside the query it works. Is there a way to only return the view once `done` has finished?

Comment: So the solution is obvious then - prefetch your data and then set the adapter

Comment: That is what I assumed I had to do but was hoping there was another way. Thank you for your help.